# my database is not updating entry on a column

Tags: java, database, postgresql, swing, pgadmin-4

i have made a program on ATM simulator in java swing and wanted to update my balance, the thing is that after submitting the amount which i want to update the java program is executing successfully without any errors but the update is not showing in database. I am using pgadmin4.

```
private void submitButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    MainAtm matm = new MainAtm();
    matm.fun();

    String sql = "UPDATE public.project SET balance=? WHERE card_no = ? AND pin = ? ;";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres", "postgres", "123");
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(depositTextField.getText()));
        pst.setString(2, matm.carad);
        pst.setString(3, matm.pen);
          pst.executeUpdate();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Balance UPdated Successfully");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Deposit.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Balance UPdated Successfully nhi hua");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you try to add a COMMIT ?

Comment: Please elaborate, are you talking about COMMIT query?

Comment: Yes. But this is not a Query. It is a statement to close transaction. When you close transaction, all UPDATE done are 'validated' and visible for others. The commit is perhaps not necessary. That depends on how you work with transaction on Postgresql ! Have you authorized AUTO-COMMIT in you java program ? If no, try to execute a COMMIT in your Java program !

Comment: i had a package full of different jforms each connected with DB.

Comment: Have you tried to add a COMMIT as proposed ? What is the result ?